# Following a file mixed with grep to exclude lines

Tags: grep, less

Basically I want to combine the function whereby you can Less a file and then Shift+F to follow the file, as you would do with Apache's access.log.

However I would like the output to ignore/hide certain lines such as lines with .jpg in or lines with my own IP.

Thanks!

SOLUTION:

Actually managed to figure it out myself using:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log|egrep -v '\.jpg|\.gif|\.js|\.css'
```

However the answer below seems a bit more elegant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if there is a reasonably long list of stuff you want to ignore, you may want to use grep -f for file. Since logs tend to rotate, --follow=name means the file is reopened when rotated. Like so:

```
tail --follow=name /da/file | grep -vf /file/with/ignore.exprs
```

Comment: cool thanks very much :) I'd actually just managed to figure it out myself, but you can have your precious points since your version seems a bit tidier